# Ignore the validation failures in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, rspec, callback

I need to test a callback that's run `before_validation`, but as I want to test only the callback I don't want test to fail when validation fails, and at the moment I get:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Preview Invalid video ID
```

I've tried out a lot of stuff. I believe that my callback method is not called when using `.save(:validate => false)` because it runs on `before_validation`.

But when I do something like this:

```
show = FactoryGirl.build :show
show.should_receive :parse_url
show.save
```

I get

```
Failure/Error: show.should_receive :parse_url
   (#<Show:0x007fd9954699e0>).parse_url(any args)
       expected: 1 time
       received: 0 times
```

despite my code in the model:

```
before_validation :parse_url, :on => :save
```

Also beside the method call I want to check the fields after they were formatted.

I'll be very thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always just catch the ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid error when it fires, and yet still test the behaviour of your before_validation. Because you catch the error, the RSpec test won't fail.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea why is my `FactoryGirl.build`, `.should_receive` and `.save` not working?